# Angulajs:Nested JSON array in ng-repeat not displaying the values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

Here is my `other_prize`JSON data

> [{"prizeno":2,"prizedesc":"Rs
>   :100,000/-","totalamt":100000,"conslation":"f","prizeticket":[{"seriesname":"RJ","digit":443581,"district":"THRISSUR"},{"seriesname":"RK","digit":633225,"district":"THIRUVANANTHAPURAM"},{"seriesname":"RL","digit":328674,"district":"KOTTAYAM"},{"seriesname":"RG","digit":753947,"district":"PALAKKAD"},{"seriesname":"RE","digit":153871,"district":"ERNAKULAM"},{"seriesname":"RD","digit":394850,"district":"PALAKKAD"},{"seriesname":"RC","digit":162287,"district":"KOZHIKKODE"},{"seriesname":"RB","digit":315428,"district":"ALAPPUZHA"},{"seriesname":"RA","digit":706397,"district":"KOTTAYAM"},{"seriesname":"RH","digit":213805,"district":"IDUKKI"},{"seriesname":"RK","digit":633435,"district":"THIRUVANANTHAPURAM"},{"seriesname":"RL","digit":801842,"district":"KOTTAYAM"},{"seriesname":"RA","digit":275046,"district":"KOTTAYAM"},{"seriesname":"RB","digit":352182,"district":"KASARGODE"},{"seriesname":"RC","digit":347419,"district":"WAYANAD"},{"seriesname":"RD","digit":909948,"district":"MALAPPURAM"},{"seriesname":"RE","digit":138627,"district":"IDUKKI"},{"seriesname":"RG","digit":583798,"district":"KOTTAYAM"},{"seriesname":"RH","digit":557799,"district":"THIRUVANANTHAPURAM"},{"seriesname":"RJ","digit":837793,"district":"PALAKKAD"}]},{"prizeno":3,"prizedesc":"Rs
>   :10,000/-","totalamt":10000,"conslation":"f","prizeticket":{"seriesname":[],"digit":52012,"district":[]}},{"prizeno":4,"prizedesc":"Rs
>   :5,000/-","totalamt":5000,"conslation":"f","prizeticket":[{"seriesname":[],"digit":3795,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":4012,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":146,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":7857,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":5581,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":4553,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":1200,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":7683,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":5295,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":7791,"district":[]}]},{"prizeno":5,"prizedesc":"Rs
>   :2,000/-","totalamt":2000,"conslation":"f","prizeticket":[{"seriesname":[],"digit":1841,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":4560,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":5234,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":8664,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":7982,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":7335,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":3849,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":8760,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":3543,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":7865,"district":[]}]},{"prizeno":6,"prizedesc":"Rs
>   :1,000/-","totalamt":1000,"conslation":"f","prizeticket":[{"seriesname":[],"digit":9090,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":8105,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":6440,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":8793,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":1035,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":7703,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":7414,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":1059,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":3944,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":7595,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":5854,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":6580,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":7488,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":4921,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":7977,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":158,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":8635,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":5597,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":1997,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":9732,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":891,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":5797,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":1806,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":8352,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":3870,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":3115,"district":[]}]},{"prizeno":7,"prizedesc":"Rs
>   :500/-","totalamt":500,"conslation":"f","prizeticket":[{"seriesname":[],"digit":8629,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":3004,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":2960,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":4344,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":9959,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":1768,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":367,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":9917,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":8403,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":947,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":2276,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":4566,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":2522,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":6844,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":430,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":8319,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":1661,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":4134,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":6830,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":5016,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":8097,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":7708,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":6577,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":134,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":5229,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":2329,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":9174,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":3712,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":7316,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":8242,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":3538,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":4243,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":7288,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":8270,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":4060,"district":[]}]},{"prizeno":8,"prizedesc":"Rs
>   :100/-","totalamt":100,"conslation":"f","prizeticket":[{"seriesname":[],"digit":7062,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":7981,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":3890,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":4997,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":3009,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":2103,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":325,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":3995,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":3587,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":1667,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":3737,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":3277,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":9228,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":6854,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":9008,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":8170,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":7364,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":199,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":4286,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":9285,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":2873,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":2636,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":337,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":8529,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":7677,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":1236,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":1142,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":5923,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":2026,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":2461,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":4696,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":9062,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":4848,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":9409,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":5198,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":5735,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":7926,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":8557,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":3853,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":713,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":8026,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":4445,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":3326,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":1485,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":2219,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":6833,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":6948,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":757,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":1226,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":5657,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":5052,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":7343,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":5222,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":6426,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":148,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":5230,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":5701,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":4860,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":2885,"district":[]},{"seriesname":[],"digit":7078,"district":[]}]}]

I am trying to display `prizeticket` nested array in an html

```
<p ng-repeat="prize in other_prize">
          {{prize.prizeno}}PRIZE
          <p ng-repeat="each in prize.prizeticket">
            {{each.district}}
          </p>
      </p>
```

But this `ng-repeat` didn't display the data

```
<p ng-repeat="each in prize.prizeticket">
                {{each.district}}
              </p>
```

However `{{prize.prizeticket}}` will returns the JSON array ,but it doesn't display the values in `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  for the outside element

```
 <div ng-repeat="prize in other_prize">
    {{prize.prizeno}}
    <p ng-repeat="each in prize.prizeticket">
      {{each.district}}
    </p>
  </div>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/2RjvJEYbumOenDEUDyvW?p=preview)**

Comment: But if prizeticket contains only one item it wll never print the value eg:`{"seriesname":[],"digit":52012,"district":[]}` i

Comment: @BlessanKurien if its not an array you need to put a ng-if and check lenght of it and display